# How to set layout_gravity programmatically?

Tags: android, android-layout

My question is simple,

How to set my buttons layout_gravity programmatically?

I found this on internet, but it simply throws me a Nullpointer exception:

```
 Button MyButton = new Button(this);

    LinearLayout.LayoutParams  lllp=(LinearLayout.LayoutParams)MyButton.getLayoutParams();
    lllp.gravity=Gravity.RIGHT;
    MyButton.setLayoutParams(lllp); 


    MyLinearLayout.addView(MyButton);
```

Any solution?

Comment: I believe you need to add the view to its parent before it will have LayoutParams that are not null.

Answer (score 621, accepted):

Java

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
params.weight = 1.0f;
params.gravity = Gravity.TOP;

button.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Kotlin

```
val params = LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
).apply {
    weight = 1.0f
    gravity = Gravity.TOP
}
button.setLayoutParams(params)
```

For gravity values and how to set gravity check [Gravity](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Gravity.html#TOP).

Basically, you should choose the `LayoutParams` depending on the parent. It can be `RelativeLayout`, `LinearLayout` etc...

Comment: For some reasons params.gravity = 80 (It should be BOTTOM, by te Docs) is just not working. I got some space betwen the bottom of the View and the Text. Its not so Bottom-aligned...

Comment: @AdamVarhegyi Without seeing your layout xml I'm not certain what your remaining problem is. But that space you're talking about may be due to padding. Try to [`setPadding()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setPadding%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29) on your `View` to 0 for the bottom.

Comment: Taking the constant value from the documentation is simply wrong, please use Gravity.TOP

Comment: this is "gravity" and he asked for "layout_gravity" ??

Comment: @usman no, this is about `layout_gravity` (that is `LayoutParams.gravity`). The `gravity` would be `button.setGravity()`

Comment: There is a lot of wrong information about gravity and layout_gravity here on SO. Many ppl think that `setGravity()` is the layout_gravity, but this is wrong. I can approve that this answer is correct for setting layout_gravity programmatically.

Comment: I think it is called gravity and not layoutGravity because it already is inside LayoutParams.

Comment: Looks like `RelativeLayout.LayoutParams` doesn't have gravity..

Answer (score 64):

I'd hate to be resurrecting old threads but this is a problem that is not answered correctly and moreover I've run into this problem myself.

Here's the long bit, if you're only interested in the answer, please scroll all the way down to the code:

`android:gravity` and `android:layout_gravity` work differently. [Here](http://sandipchitale.blogspot.sg/2010/05/linearlayout-gravity-and-layoutgravity.html)'s an article I've read that helped me.

**GIST of article: gravity affects view after height/width is assigned. So gravity centre will not affect a view that is done MATCH_PARENT (think of it as auto margin). layout_gravity centre WILL affect view that is MATCH_PARENT (think of it as auto pad).**

Basically, `android:layout_gravity` CANNOT be access programmatically, only android:gravity.
In the OP's case and my case, the accepted answer does not place the button vertically centre.

To improve on Karthi's answer:

```java
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

params.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
button.setLayoutParams(params);
```

[Link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.LayoutParams.html) to `LinearLayout.LayoutParams`.

`android:layout_gravity` shows "No related methods" meaning cannot be accessed programatically.
Whereas gravity is a field in the class.

Comment: Also to add on that gravity auto-margins (for lack of a better term) based on the LinearLayout parent's orientation. The article link provided will help.

Answer (score 23):

I had a similar problem with programmatically setting layout_gravity on buttons in a GridLayout.

The trick was to set gravity on the button layoutParams **AFTER** the button was added to a parent (GridLayout), **otherwise the gravity would be ignored**.

```
grid.addView(button)
((GridLayout.LayoutParams)button.getLayoutParams()).setGravity(int)
```

Comment: How do I change the layout_gravity for the whole GridLayout?

Comment: Still true in 2020! Why?

Comment: Thank you SO MUCH. Still true in 2021 (nearly 2022 btw)

Answer (score 20):

```
MyButton.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
```

For layout_gravity use the answer stated by "karthi". This method sets gravity to place the children inside the view.

Comment: It just gravity, not layout_gravity.

Comment: Okay then tell me if layout_gravity equals setGravity, then how I set the gravity?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setGravity(int) , look at this..

Comment: Posting an enormous Document is not solution sorry,

Comment: look for setGravity method in the link.., somehow the redirection to the exact method is not working..

Comment: If the asker is refering to `layout_gravity` of the view within its container, and not `gravity` of the content of the view, then Karthi's answer below is the correct one.

Comment: This did not work (at least not in API 7). Using LayoutParams works perfectly (see other answers).

Answer (score 19):

```
layoutParams2.gravity = Gravity.RIGHT|Gravity.BOTTOM;
```

use this to add mor than one gravity

Comment: Nope, that's how:
`gravity = Gravity.END or Gravity.BOTTOM`

Comment: @OleksandrNos What you wrote is the Kotlin syntax, what Omar wrote is the java syntax.

Answer (score 17):

If you want to change the `layout_gravity` of an existing view, do this:

```java
((FrameLayout.LayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams()).gravity = Gravity.BOTTOM;
```

Remember to use the right `LayoutParams` based on the Layout type your view is in. Ex:

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams
```

Answer (score 13):

**KOTLIN setting more than one gravity on FrameLayout without changing size:**

```
     // assign more than one gravity,Using the operator "or"
    var gravity = Gravity.RIGHT or Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL
     // update gravity
    (pagerContainer.layoutParams as FrameLayout.LayoutParams).gravity = gravity
     // refresh layout
     pagerContainer.requestLayout()
```

Comment: It 's save my time... THX

Comment: requestLayout() saved me ^_^

Answer (score 10):

This question is old but I just had the same problem and solved it like this

```
LayoutParams lay = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT)
lay.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
```

Comment: @Muzikant.. ok.. i didnt noticed first.. but now its clear to me..Thanks

Comment: Does this only work by specifying what kind of layout it is first? Like RelativeLayout.LayoutParams ... instead of just LayoutParams

Comment: RelativeLayout.LayoutParams use other flags to set gravity of the view (rightOf, centerInParent, centerVertical). This workaround is for LinearLayouts childrens

Answer (score 5):

If you want to put a view in the center of parent, you can do with following code..

```
public class myLayout extends LinearLayout {

    public myLayout(Context context) {
      super(context);

      RelativeLayout vi = (RelativeLayout) ((LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)).inflate(
            R.layout.activity_main, null);
      LinearLayout.LayoutParams cc = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
      cc.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
      this.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
      this.addView(vi);
  }
}
```

these code section make LinearLayout put the first view elements in the center of parent.
So, we system don't consider the initial width and high to arrange view in the center .
I do the code section well.

Comment: i - italic ))))

Answer (score 5):

I use someting like that: (Xamarin and C# code)

```
  LinearLayout linLayout= new LinearLayout(this); 
    linLayout.SetGravity(GravityFlags.Center);

    TextView txtView= new TextView(this);  
     linLayout.AddView(txtView);
```

the SetGravity puts my textView in the center of the layout.
So **SetGravity** layout property refer to layout **content**

Answer (score 5):

In case you need to set Gravity for a View use the following

```
Button b=new Button(Context);
b.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
```

For setting layout_gravity for the Button
use gravity field for the layoutparams as

```
LayoutParams lp=new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
lp.gravity=Gravity.CENTER;
```

try this 
hope this clears
thanks

Answer (score 3):

The rest of the answers are right, I want to add more explaination. The layout_gravity is about how to position the view in parent view.

You must set gravity **after method parentView.addView() ** was called.  We can see the code:

```
public void setLayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams params) {
    if (params == null) {
        throw new NullPointerException("Layout parameters cannot be null");
    }
    mLayoutParams = params;
    resolveLayoutParams();
    if (mParent instanceof ViewGroup) {
        ((ViewGroup) mParent).onSetLayoutParams(this, params);
    }
    requestLayout();
}
```

And the problem of null pointer is because it's not calling addView before getLayoutParams().

The annotation was already said "This method may return null if this View is not attached to a parent ViewGroup or {@link#setLayoutParams(android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams)} was not invoked successfully. When a View is attached to a parent ViewGroup, this method must not return null."

Comment: This bit me too...it's not obvious you have to set gravity after the addView() is called.  You'd think you'd set everything up on the new view and then add it so this is unintuitive :-P

Answer (score 3):

Modify the existing layout params and set layout params again

```
//Get the current layout params and update the Gravity
(iv.layoutParams as FrameLayout.LayoutParams).gravity = Gravity.START
//Set layout params again (this updates the view)
iv.layoutParams = layoutParams
```

Comment: In my case there is LinearLayout inside FrameLayout, and gravity for LinearLayout works only if I cast it to FrameLayout, example:

`@BindingAdapter("android:stateLayoutGravity")
fun LinearLayout.setStateLayoutGravity(gravity: Int) {
    (this.layoutParams as FrameLayout.LayoutParams).apply {
        this.gravity = gravity
    }
}`

Answer (score 2):

to RelativeLayout, try this code , it works for me:
`yourLayoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);`

Answer (score 2):

**Perfectly Working!!!** None of the above answer works for me. In Xml file setting gravity and setting layout_gravity is different. Check out the below code

```
// here messageLL is the linear layout in the xml file
// Before adding any view just remove all views
   messageLL.removeAllViews();
// FrameLayout is the parent for LinearLayout
FrameLayout.LayoutParams params = new 
   FrameLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
   params.gravity = Gravity.CENTER|Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL;
   messageLL.setLayoutParams(params);
   messageText.setVisibility(View.GONE);
   messageNoText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
   messageLL.addView(messageNoText);
```

*Also check  [This,where you can find clear explanation about gravity and layout_gravity .](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27086486/how-to-set-both-gravity-and-layout-gravity-of-a-linearlayout-programatically)*

Answer (score 2):

Most of above answer are right, so written a **helper methods,** so you can use it 
directly in you project .

> set **`layout_gravity`** programmtically

```
// gravity types : Gravity.BOTTOM, Gravity.START etc.
// view : can be any view example : button, textview, linearlayout, image etc.

// for single view
   public static void setLayoutGravity(int gravity, View view){
     ((LinearLayout.LayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams()).gravity = gravity;
    }


// for mulitple views
  public static void setLayoutGravity(int gravity, View ...view){
        for(View item : view)
            ((LinearLayout.LayoutParams) item.getLayoutParams()).gravity = gravity;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I switched from LinearLayout.LayoutParams to RelativeLayout.LayoutParams to finally get the result I was desiring on a custom circleview I created.

But instead of gravity you use addRule

RelativeLayout.LayoutParams mCircleParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(circleheight,circleheight);

```
    mCircleParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 int width=getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels; 
 LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams
                    (width, width);

            params.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;

           iv_main_text = new HTextView(getContext());
            iv_main_text.setLayoutParams(params);
            iv_main_text.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
            iv_main_text.setTextSize(60);
            iv_main_text.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            iv_main_text.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
FloatingActionButton sendFab = new FloatingActionButton(this);
    FrameLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    layoutParams.setMargins(32, 32, 32, 32);
    layoutParams.gravity = Gravity.END|Gravity.BOTTOM;
    sendFab.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
    sendFab.setImageResource(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_send);
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this code

```
    Button btn = new Button(YourActivity.this);
    btn.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER | Gravity.TOP);
    btn.setText("some text");
```

or

```
    btn.setGravity(Gravity.TOP);
```

Comment: OP asks for `layout_gravity` not `gravitiy`.