# How can I set layout_gravity dynamically in android?

Tags: android-layout

How can I set layout_gravity programmatically?

I need to set position of a button `LEFT` or `CENTER` or `RIGHT` in a particular layout, I used the `myButton.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);` but, it sets the gravity of button's text.

Answer (score 0):

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8049860/645270) by putting your title in the search bar. The short version: Use `LayoutParams`