# Arrange buttons from bottom instead of top?

Tags: java, android

I am dynamically creating the buttons. But the problem is they are getting created from top. I want to create it from bottom .

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {
    int i, j, butNum, lay1num = 1, lay2num = 100, lay3num = 100, store;
    Button[] Button;
    EditText numBut;
    LinearLayout mainLayout;
    LinearLayout[] subLayout;
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        butNum = 5;
        Button = new Button[butNum];
        subLayout = new LinearLayout[3];
        LinearLayout mainLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
        mainLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
        mainLayout.setWeightSum(90);
        mainLayout.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
        layoutGen();

        for (j = 0; j < butNum; j++) {
            int value = j + 1;
            Button[j] = new Button(this);
            Button[j].setText("" + value);
            Button[j].setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            Button[j].setTextSize(20);
            Button[j].setTag(value);
            Button[j].setId(j);
            subLayout[0].addView(Button[j]);
            Button[j].setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        mainLayout.addView(subLayout[0], params);

        setContentView(mainLayout);
    }
```

Is there anyway I can create buttons which are aligned to the bottom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
subLayout.setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM);
```

You nay need to set size of layout to match_parent.

Eventually You may set a layout_gravity like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8049620/how-to-set-layout-gravity-programmaticaly)