# Android - Set Layout_Gravity programmatically for LinearLayout

Tags: java, android, position, android-linearlayout, layout-gravity

I've got the following problem: I implemented a `HorizontalScrollView` which contains in one case a `LinearLayout` and an `ImageView`. In this case the image is about 50% of the screen width. So I want to center it. Unfortunately the only way I found to center it is, to use `layout_gravity="center"` on the `LinearLayout`.

Here's my xml:

```
<HorizontalScrollView
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView                    
                android:src="@drawable/myImg"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:layout_height="150dp"/>

        </LinearLayout>

    </HorizontalScrollView>
```

But I need to set the `layout_gravity` programmatically. Does anybody has an idea how I can achieve this or knows a different way? All the things I found via Google are not working for me like [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8049620/1331671).

Thanks!

Comment: have you tried encapsultaing the ImageView in a LinearLayout and setting the parameters for that layout as shown in the post you visited?

Comment: yeah, i've tried it... not working

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Do somethings like this :

```
   LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams();
   lp.gravity= Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL; 
   myImg.setLayoutParams(lp);
```

**UPDATE :**
Another way to do this :

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            params.weight = 1.0f;
            params.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;

            imageView.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Comment: So, for the gravity value to work, the element must have MATCH_WIDTH set or occupy the full width of its parent. If this is not the case, then it must have a weight value of 100%(which makes its occupy the parent fully), only then does setting gravity work.

Answer (score 8):

Put the `ImageView` in a `FrameLayout` like this:

*Removed extra code*

```
ImageView image = new ImageView(mContext);
image.setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(width, height, gravity));
```

More info [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/FrameLayout.LayoutParams.html).

Comment: not working... but anyway, why shall i put the imageview inside a `FrameLayout` and put FrameLayout.Params to the imageView and not the parent?

Comment: the third parameter is not `gravity` it's `weight`!

Answer (score 1):

I think , this one will work for you

```
FrameLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new ScrollView.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
 layoutParams1.gravity(YourGravity);
yourImage.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
```