# How to set layout_gravity for Textview inside Relative layout

Tags: android, android-layout, textview, android-relativelayout

I need to set layout gravity for Textview which is inside Relative layout,
I do this via xml but how to do it programmatically?

```
<Relativelayout>
    <Textview
     android:gravity="left"
     android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|right"/>
</Relativelayout>
```

I need to set gravity and layout_gravity programmatically.

Comment: Just use center in parent and align parent right.

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17965784/android-set-layout-gravity-programmatically-for-linearlayout/17965963) might help you.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

Use [**`RelativeLayout.LayoutParams`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.html)

> Specifies how a view is positioned within a `RelativeLayout`. The relative layout containing the view uses the value of these layout parameters to determine where to position the view on the screen. If the view is not contained within a relative layout, these attributes are ignored.

**Sample Code**

```
TextView textView=findViewById(R.id.spn);
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams =
                (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)textView.getLayoutParams();    
layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
textView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
  RelativeLayout relativeLayout=new RelativeLayout(this);
  TextView textView=new TextView(this);
  RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams=new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
  layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
  layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
  textView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
  relativeLayout.addView(textView);
```

Comment: you are genius.

Answer (score 0):

Create a layoutParams object, define your gravity there and set it to your textview.

Answer (score 0):

```
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
    params.weight = 1.0f;
    params.gravity = Gravity.TOP;

button.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Replace `LinearLayout.LayoutParams`with `RelativeLayout.LayoutParams`

Answer (score 0):

```
 Textview tx= new Textview(this);
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new Relative.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
params.weight = 1.0f;
params.gravity = Gravity.center_vertical;

tx.setLayoutParams(params):
```

or another option check this link
https://android--code.blogspot.com/2015/05/android-textview-layout-gravity.html