# how i set layout_gravity in java file

Tags: android, layout-gravity

I want to set layout in Java code file. I use the following code to set this `layout` to center

```
        theme = db.getthemeByID(id);
        String themePath = theme.getFilepath();
        int resid = getResources().getIdentifier(themePath, "drawable", getPackageName());
        //layout for book theme
        LinearLayout LLT = new LinearLayout(context);
        LLT.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    >>>>LLT.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(500, 650, Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL));
        LLT.setBackgroundResource(resid);   
        // add view 
        VF.addView(LLT);
```

I'm still getting error on this line:

`LLT.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(500, 650, Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL));`

How can I do if I want to set `layout` to `center_horizontal`

Comment: What error? Post log if possible..

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because the third param in that constructor is `weight`, not `Gravity`.

Try removing that (so the `LayoutParams` only have two arguments, `height` and `width`), and then in the next line you can do

```
LLT.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
```

Comment: if i use LLT.setGravity(Gravity.center_horizontal).this layout not set to center horizontal.i have tried it

Answer (score 0):

```
labelTV.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
```

use this to set layout gravity programmatically...

or this will help you..

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
params.weight = 1.0f;
params.gravity=CENTER_HORIZONTAL;
```

See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8049620/how-to-set-layout-gravity-programmaticaly) to see this in more clear manner