# how to change the x of view in relativelayout Programmatically in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

i have a view in relativeleayout , I want to change the place of the view to the middle of relativeleayout:
what I do ?

the xml  :

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/partieoption"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:weightSum="6"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

   <ImageView 
       android:id="@+id/photo2"
       android:src="@drawable/loglog"
       android:layout_width="50dp"
       android:layout_height="50dp"
   />
</RelativeLayout>
```

and

```
RelativeLayout partieoption = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.partieoption);
ImageView x = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.photo2);
```

Comment: and where is that view? are you talking about your ImageView? please post your complete xml

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to create a [RelativeLayout.LayoutParams](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.html) for your `ImageView` with a CENTER_IN_PARENT *rule*, then apply it with `setLayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams params)`.

Here's an example:

```
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.iv_image);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)imageView.getLayoutParams();
    layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
    imageView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 <ImageView 
                        android:id="@+id/photo2"
                        android:src="@drawable/loglog"
                        android:layout_width="50dp"
                        android:layout_height="50dp"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
 />
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8049620/how-to-set-layout-gravity-programmaticaly

Answer (score 0):

For moving the view, add this code

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
Point size = new Point();
display.getSize(size);
int width = size.x;
RelativeLayout partieoption = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.partieoption);
      ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.photo2);
ObjectAnimator transAnimation= ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(iv, x, iv.getX(), width/2);
  transAnimation.setDuration(3000);
  transAnimation.start();
```

Comment: nooooo  , the middle of relativelayout , not the middle of scran !!

Comment: So assign width = partieoption.getWidth() and rest remains the same.

Answer (score 0):

use the gravity attribute in your xml, like this:

```
android:layout_gravity="center"
```

in your case, i think will be like this:

```
<RelativeLayout
android:id="@+id/partieoption"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:weightSum="6"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<ImageView 
   android:id="@+id/photo2"
   android:src="@drawable/loglog"
   android:layout_width="50dp"
   android:layout_height="50dp"
   android:layout_gravity="center"
/>
</RelativeLayout>
```