# android gravity in textview is not working

Tags: android

hi programmers my big respect to all of you.
im new here in android programming.

im having a problem in working my radio button with a function of gravity in my textview by aligning them from center, left and right.

My API is 23

and im following this tutorial [youtube tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pZaRNVwKAy4&index=15&list=PLB03EA9545DD188C3) but mine is not working

```
package com.example.testavd;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnCheckedChangeListener {
    TextView txtV;
    RadioGroup rg;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        txtV = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textOut);
        rg = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.rdG);
        rg.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);

        Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

        b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                txtV.setText("boom");

            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch(checkedId){
        case R.id.rbCenter:
            txtV.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            break;
        case R.id.rbLeft:
            txtV.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);
            break;
        case R.id.rbRight:
            txtV.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
            break;

        }
    }
}
```

> My XML

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.testavd.MainActivity" >

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/rdG"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
         >
        <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/rbRight"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/rbLeft"
        android:layout_below="@+id/rbLeft"
        android:layout_marginTop="36dp"
        android:text="Right" />

        <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/rbLeft"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="17dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button1"
        android:text="Left" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/rbCenter"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/rbRight"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:text="Center" />

    </RadioGroup>



    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="Button" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textOut"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:text="Output"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />



</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use **android:gravity="center_horizontal"** on the RadioGroup to center the radiobuttons.Also gravity doesn't work in RelativeLayout You have to align according to parent or other widgets. If want to use gravity or layout_gravity use linearlayout.

Answer (score 0):

Your `TextView` parent is a `RelativeLayout`, you cannot use `gravity` with `RelativeLayout`.

Try using in xml layout file

`android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"`

or in `Activity`

```
 case R.id.rbCenter:
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,   ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        params.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
        txtV.setLayoutParams(params);
            break;
```

Comment: thank you sir.. so its the xml is my problem.
you helped me a lot.. more powers

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1 :**

`android:gravity` sets the gravity of the content of the View its used on.

you have used gravity in `TextView` having `wrap_content` width, so it will not make any diferrence as view is having width as much as content.

try it with `match_parent` width and you will see difference.

```
android:layout_width="macth_parent"
```

**Solution 2 :**

use `android:layout_gravity`, it sets the gravity of the `View` or `Layout` in its parent.

no matter how much content your TextView is having, it will set whole TextView in center/right/left aligned.

To make it more affective make sure following things :

1. When you are using `android:gravity` use width of view as `match_parent`.
2. When you are using `android:layout_gravity` use width of view as `wrap_content`.

refer this to programmatically set `layout_gravity` : [How to set layout_gravity PROGRAMATICALLY?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8049620/how-to-set-layout-gravity-programatically)