# Programmatically add views to LinearLayout with both gravity and weight

Tags: android, android-layout

I have LinearLayout generated in xml, this one:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/available_themes_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingTop="6dp"
        android:paddingBottom="6dp"/>
```

I'm trying to add some custom views to this layout and place them evenly along layout:

```
BiColorCircleView lightOrangeCircleView = new BiColorCircleView(getCurrentActivity());
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                1.0f);
params.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
lightOrangeCircleView.setLayoutParams(params);
availableThemesLayout.addView(lightOrangeCircleView);
```

But at the end I achieve that only weight is applied and my views is aligned to left side. Thought, if weight is not set - gravity works nice.

Could somebody point me to way of solving this problem?

Comment: When using `weight`s, make sure the appropriate `width` or `height` is set as `0dp`.

Comment: Have you tried setting gravity after adding the view to the layout?

Comment: @Nerd, tried that, with width since orientation is horizontal.

Comment: @akash93,just tried that, no changes, gravity is not applied.

Comment: There are a few ways given here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8049620/how-to-set-layout-gravity-programmatically

Comment: @ akash93, a lot of variants, thanks for pointing that out, but neither of them works for me. Looks like I need to go away from LinearLayout =(

Answer (score 1):

```
        LinearLayout availableThemesLayout = new LinearLayout(null);
        ImageView lightOrangeCircleView = new ImageView(null);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                0,
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                1.0f);
        FrameLayout frameLayout = new FrameLayout(null);
        availableThemesLayout.addView(frameLayout, params);

        FrameLayout.LayoutParams frameParams = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
                FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        frameParams.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
        frameLayout.addView(lightOrangeCircleView, params);
```

Try this.

Comment: Why do you create views with null instead of context? This will throw NPE.
And this doesn't work too(