# How to set layout gravity for activity root view

Tags: android, android-layout

I get the root view (Which in my case happens to be RelativeLayout) using the below code:

```
final ViewGroup viewGroup = (ViewGroup) ((ViewGroup) this
        .findViewById(android.R.id.content)).getChildAt(0);
```

Source: [Get root view from current activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4486034/get-root-view-from-current-activity)

Now I want to set the size and the layout gravity of the root view. But I don't know the layout type of its parent

The below code works when the view I want to set it's layout params is inside a LinearLayout.

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
params.weight = 1.0f;
params.gravity = Gravity.TOP;

button.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Source: [How to set layout_gravity programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8049620/how-to-set-layout-gravity-programmatically/25701030)

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need `DecorView.LayoutParams`.

The root view is added to a DecorView, which is attached to the Activity's Window.

[PhoneWindow.java](https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/com/android/internal/policy/PhoneWindow.java)

---

Since the DecorView in question isn't accessible to apps in general, you can use `FrameLayout.LayoutParams`.

Comment: Thank you, it turns out that the parent of the root view is a FrameLayout, as my app crashed and AS says can't cast RelativeLayout (root) to FrameLayout when I use rootview.setLayoutParams(params);

Comment: Oh right, the DecorView you're using is probably from the ViewPager class, since the internal one is hidden. I guess ViewPager's extends RelativeLayout and not FrameLayout.