# How can I align whole TextView (not text in it) to the right side of parent

Tags: android, android-xml

I am making chat app and I want to align text message to right side of parrent (which in that case is LinearLayout).

Here is what I get: [image: picture]

And here is what I want: [image: picture]

And here is my XML code for this layout:

```
            <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/chatMessages"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/background2"
            android:text="Losowy tekst"
            android:textSize="25dp"></TextView>


    </LinearLayout>
```

So please help me, how can I do it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set layout\_gravity programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8049620/how-to-set-layout-gravity-programmatically)

Answer (score 1):

On your TextView, use  `android:layout_gravity="end"`

Comment: Ok thanks, but how can I do it programmatically in java.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8049620/how-to-set-layout-gravity-programmatically

Answer (score 0):

**please try this**

LayoutParams la= new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
la.gravity = Gravity.END;